# Sort by day of the week after filtering, in different rows

Tags: php, sql

What my application is currently doing: initially, it shows records of a database. I choose between 2 dates, I press filter. It only shows records them.

What I want to do: I want to categorize the result by days. To show, Monday 5 feb, these registrations, Tuesday 6, these, etc, for every day of the week. I want them categorized in rows and columns in the result.

The way it displays right now:

Record1

record2

record3

The way i want it displayed:

Monday 5 feb

record1

record2

Tuesday 6 feb

record3

record4

Etc. Sample of my code, changed some things:

```
       $connect = mysqli_connect(1,2,3,4)
         $query =  "select startdate, registerdate, name FROM `table1` order by
registerdate desc";  
            $result = mysqli_query($connect,  $query);  
     <html>  
          <head>  
               <title></title>  
                    <div id="tablediv">  
                         <table class="table table-bordered" id="testTable">  
                              <tr>  
                                   <th width="30%">start</th>  
                                   <th width="30%">registered</th>  
                                   <th width="30%">name</th>  
                              </tr>   
                         <?php  
                         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                         {  
                         ?>  
                              <tr>  
                                   <td><?php echo $row["startdate"]; ?></td>  
                                   <td><?php echo $row["registerdate"]; ?></td>                                
                                   <td> <?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>  
                              </tr>
```

filter file:

```
   $query =  "start, registerdate, name FROM `table1`"  WHERE registerdate BETWEEN '".$_POST["from_date"]."' AND '".$_POST["to_date"]. "' order by registerdate desc
```

Comment: I'm struggling to see what this has to do with c#. This looks at lot like PHP.

Comment: What have you tried so far to come to an answer?

Comment: 1) Sorry, changed the tag to php.
2) I have not come with an answer, is it possible to arrange the result and display it in days?

Answer (score 0):

If your rows are already ordered, it's quite simple to achieve this.

Check this example:

```
<?php

$dates = [
    '2018-01-01',
    '2018-01-01',
    '2018-01-02',
    '2018-01-03',
    '2018-01-04',
    '2018-01-04',
    '2018-01-04',
    '2018-01-05',
    '2018-01-05',
    '2018-01-06',    
];

$lastDate = '';
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $datetime = new DateTime($date);
    if ($date != $lastDate) {
        $lastDate = $date;
        echo "\n" . $datetime->format('j M Y') . "\n";
    }
    echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d') . " - your row here.\n";
}
```

Which will output:

```
1 Jan 2018 
2018-01-01 - your row here. 
2018-01-01 - your row here. 

2 Jan 2018 
2018-01-02 - your row here. 

3 Jan 2018 
2018-01-03 - your row here. 

4 Jan 2018 
2018-01-04 - your row here. 
2018-01-04 - your row here. 
2018-01-04 - your row here. 

5 Jan 2018 
2018-01-05 - your row here. 
2018-01-05 - your row here. 

6 Jan 2018 
2018-01-06 - your row here.
```

Have a play with it here: https://3v4l.org/f7TDr